# How to pass variables in codeigniter 2

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have following

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Hello extends CI_Controller {
  var $name = 'test';
  function index() {
    $this->name = 'Andy';
    $data['name'] = $this->name;
    $this->load->view('you_view', $data);  // THIS WORKS
  }

  function you() {
    $data['name'] = $this->name;
    $this->load->view('you_view', $data);  // BUT THIS DOESN'T WORK
  }
}
```

My question is how to I pass the `$this->name = 'Andy';` to `you()` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is being set in a different method of the controller, which equates to another request in your code, you will need to store it in a session variable to have it persist across page requests.

```
function index() {
    $this->name = 'Andy';
    $data['name'] = $this->name;
    $this->session->set_userdata('name', $this->name);
    $this->load->view('you_view', $data);  // THIS WORKS
  }

  function you() {
    $data['name'] = $this->session->userdata('name');
    $this->load->view('you_view', $data);  // BUT THIS DOESN'T WORK
  }
```

Comment: Yes this will work, reminder for newbie you need to autoload session and config encryption to store in session variable.

Answer (score 0):

If its a value that is part of the class you can put it in the constructor

```
 class Hello extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    // will be available to any method in the class
    $this->name = 'andy';

}
```